# Is there an English word derived from τάσσω, with a similar meaning of arranging/organising?

Tags: word-request, derivation, ancient-greek

Apologies if this is the wrong site to ask this on.

I am looking for an English word that is derived from Ancient Greek τάσσω, meaning *I arrange*, *I draw up*, or *I order*. I would like a word that evokes this Hellenism, with a similar meaning in English, but the only derivations I can find are through τακτικός -> English *tact*, *tactful*.

I do not mind using technical/uncommon language, but I am unaware of any resources for finding such derivations!

Comment: Are you looking for an English verb "with similar meaning"? Or will a noun do?

Comment: FWIW _tact_ / _tactful_ are from Latin _tango_ "I touch".

Comment: @psmears You're right, although *tactics/tactical* is from τακτικός. It's somewhat of a coincidence that they have the same four initial letters as *tact/tactful*, though both sets are ultimately from the PIE **tag-* meaning "to touch."

Comment: @psmears Hmm... - maybe this is an issue with Wiktionary then? They seem to have [it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tactic#English) as coming from τακτικός.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi: That link is to the definition for *tactic*, not *tact* / *tactful* ?

Comment: Is the word you are looking for, [cognates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate)? Are you looking for English cognates of the Greek word "τάσσω"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The word you are looking for would be **taxonomy**, from τάσσω, fut. τάξω, to arrange in a certain order, e.g. of troops. Τακτικός is that which is required for the arrangement: the tactics.

Comment: Also "taxon". ___

Comment: as a verb: "taxonomize"

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I forgot about this term/stem - I appreciate your help greatly in shaking up my memory.

Comment: "taxonomy" derives from τάσσω and νόμος (usually meaning "law", for example "law and order" is perfectly translated as "νόμος και τάξη", although in this case it has a more abstract meaning closer to "science" or "technique"). The direct greek equivalent is "ταξινόμηση", which means "classification" -- for example, a person sorting incoming mail for further processing is called ταξινόμος.

Arranging things in a certain order is better expressed with συντάσσω, for example you would command troops to assume formation by saying "συνταχθείτε".

Answer (score 9):

Another common English word is **syntax**: literally the "ordering together" of words, from [συντάσσω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dsunta%2Fssw) > [σύνταξις](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dsu%2Fntacis).

Answer (score 3):

taxi, taximeter, task, tax, taxis, taxology, taxation

All seem to also stem from τάσσω.
Taximeter and taxology sound particularly Hellenic as they are a mixture of 2 Hellenic based words.

- meter - from Greek μέτρο (measure)
- logy - from Greek [λογία](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-logy)

See also [a relative article](https://ewonago.wordpress.com/tag/etymology-of-task/) on the etymology of the words above.

Task is also close to the original meaning, especially if used as a verb.

E.g. He was tasked to paint the fence.

Comment: Good examples! About *task*, isn't that ultimately from Latin *tango*?

Comment: Good observation. As far as I could find:
- Task comes from the old French tasque from tasche (duty) from the Latin tasca (a duty, assessment) from taxa, which is relatedto the Greek verb tasso (put in order, evaluate; τάσσω). Source: https://ewonago.wordpress.com/tag/etymology-of-task/
- Tango is more related to the touch and movement.

Comment: @Cerberus: It seems like all of these are descendants of Latin tango, but tango is in turn cognate with τάσσω. So a word like taxi would be cognate with τάσσω, but not not a descendant of it.

Comment: Just to clarify what Cerberus and @BenCrowell said, being "related to" τάσσω is not the same thing as descending from it. The Greek is more like the uncle of the English than the parent. See [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tax#etymonline_v_43945) for the direct relationship. So while "taxology" (and "taxonomy" work (and "taxis", too), the others are more distantly related.

Answer (score 0):

posting this after the answer has been accepted, but here is another option if you allow synonyms to τάσσω.

κοσμέω has a synonymous meaning to tasso and the following English words seem to be related:

cosmos
cosmetology
cosmonaut
cosmogony
cosmopolite
cosmetic
macrocosm